# Calculating CMRR for a Long-Tailed Pair in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice, differential-amplifier

I am trying to understand the behaviour of Long-Tailed Pair amplifiers and have been given the following simulation circuit (The PMOS models have all parameters defined):

[image]

Firstly, I am generating a single-ended differential signal in order to determine the differential gain of the system. That is understandable enough, I get the following graph and calculate gain by taking two current samples at the linear region.

[image]

I get around 100 Siemens for the transconductance, which I calculate to about 40 dB? taking Rd to be one in this case (not sure if this is an acceptable estimation)

However, not I am supposed to get a value for the common mode gain, and I do this by sweeping both gates simultaneously between the supply rails.

[image]

[image]

However, I have no idea, which values to take and what to use to calculate the gain, along with the CMRR.

Also, I need to do the same experiment with a resistor instead of the current source - which value should I use for that?

Thank you in advance for the assistance!

Yordan

Comment: I hate to say it, but have you read [the Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common-mode_rejection_ratio) on the topic and do you feel that you follow it well?

Comment: "...have been given the following simulation circuit."  Given by whom?  Your outputs are shorted to ground...is that intentional?

Comment: Yeah, I read information online but, no, I feel like I follow it badly - the reason being that I get a CMRR of less than one for the resistor case. That does make sense in a way, because logically the circuit does not reject common mode noise, due to the current varying completely with the common mode voltage. 
As for @SteKulov's question - it is an exercise, but I am failing to make much sense of the directions given. Also, it is intentional as I am taking the current as an output and having it shorted to ground enables it to go as high as it can.